# Get ad computers from two different domains

Tags: powershell

I'm using below statement to get server lists from AD using windows server filter. I've two different domain "abc.com" and another "anil.abc.com". I've an access to read information from both the domains, when i run the script i get data only from the "abc.com" , but cannot get the server lists from "anil.abc.com". Can you please help what i can use to get a data from both using a single script ?

My script

```
$ScriptPath = Get-Location
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties * | SORT Name | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File $ScriptPath\ServerListNames.txt
```

Comment: Did you try the [`Get-ADComputer -Server`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer) to refer to the other domain (server)?

Comment: I tried below but no output in the text

Get-ADComputer -Server abc.com -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "windows*server") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -SearchBase "DC=abc,DC=com" -Properties * | SORT Name | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File $ScriptPath\ServerListNames.txt

Comment: As we do not have access to your environment, you need to troubleshoot this your self: what happens when you remove everything arround it (including the `-filter` etc.) and just do:`Get-ADComputer -Server abc.com`? Does it list any/all your computers on the `abc.com` domain? If not, what if you use an explicit server, like: `-server servername.abc.com`?

Comment: Thank you , Worked as belowThis will get the details from my current dc.
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties * | SORT Name | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File $ScriptPath\ServerListNames.txt

For a different DC i have to update as below, and in last -append to add hostnames in to the text file. 
Get-ADComputer -Server anil.abc.com -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties * | SORT Name | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File $ScriptPath\ServerListNames.txt -Append

Answer (score 0):

Worked as belowThis will get the details from my current dc. Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "windowsserver*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties * | SORT Name | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File $ScriptPath\ServerListNames.txt For a different DC i have to update as below, and in last -append to add hostnames in to the text file. Get-ADComputer -Server anil.abc.com -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "windowsserver*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties * | SORT Name | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File $ScriptPath\ServerListNames.txt